# Embedding pay now button

Tags: button, paypal, user-experience

I currently use Big Cartel for my online shop. Big Cartel is a web-based eCommerce solution specifically designed to help artists, whether musicians or crafters, sell their merchandise online easily. So when customers order my products online they can checkout through big cartel which they have an option to use PayPal after trying name, address, email address, etc, however, to add a more efficient/speedy checkout so they don't have to type out all of their info, I embedded a PayPal express button. The problem is when they order by clicking the pp button, it doesn't take away from my current stock resulting in overselling. It's acting like a separate entity and I can't see what they actually purchased- Only a PayPal message that they sent me funds. Obviously I want to avoid overselling and need to know how to get the PayPal button to collaborate with my big cartel shop when someone purchases with the "pay now" PayPal button. Is there an additional code I'm missing? Any advice and help with this issue is very appreciated! (This is the first time I've used code and inserted anything before so I'm not tech lingo savvy)

Comment: I added the user-experience tag, it seems like that may be the domain of your problem. If you could give more information as to how the order process works right now and how you want it to work? what do you mean by "big cartel"? what differentiates "big cartels" from normal orders? Giving more information may assist in your question receiving a good answer

Comment: Sure! Sorry, I thought this help site was associated with the Big Cartel. Big Cartel is a web-based eCommerce solution specifically designed to help artists, whether musicians or crafters, sell their merchandise online easily. So customers order my products but to add a more efficient checkout (so they don't have to type out all of their info) I added a PayPal express button. The problem is when they order through the pp button I added, it doesn't take away from my current stock. It's acting like a separate entity and I can't see what they actually purchased. Only that they sent me funds.

Comment: edit the question to add the information there please

Comment: Ok thank you. Just edited my original post. Hopefully that is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You must verify that you have entered your PayPal API information in Big Cartel settings. You should also add "Return URL" in your Admin Panel.

I would also suggest you to use Sandbox and test it yourself so you don't have to worry when real orders come in.

The API login credentials look like this:

```
USER=API_username
PWD=API_password
SIGNATURE=API_signature
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm sorry, I'm not exactly sure what part of your response means but I'm going to try and follow your instructions. what does API stand for?

Comment: And the API log in credentials you are referring to.... Is that code that I need to add after the PayPal button code I added?

Comment: Login to your PayPal account and then go to your profile. Look for the API credentials link on that page. API stands for Application Programming Interface. It allows Big Cartel to connect to PayPal to retrieve your account specific information. API credentials will go to your Big Cartel Admin Panel (not the button code).

Comment: Thank you so much!